# What is the meaning of the phrase "What it could do though"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Could you please explain the meaning of the phrase "what it could do though"?
Is it usually used as below?

What it could do though is S+V

Comment: Please provide more context about the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What it could do though" is just the phrase "What it could do" with "though" added as an adverb meaning "nevertheless" or "however". The phrase might be used like this:

> The material would be very expensive and difficult to work with. What it could do though is increase the product's heat resistant.

If you're going to use it as "what it could do though is..." then some complement to "is" has to follow, like a bare infinitive, an adjective, or a noun. If I understand you correctly, then the answer to your second question is no. That "is" cannot be followed by the subject of a verb phrase.